# Почему таджикский, узбекский, но казацкий?

Tags: орфография, суффиксы

**По правилу** суффикс относительных прилагательных ***СК*** является **основным** вариантом: швед – шведский, киргиз – киргизский, казах – казахский, Ташкент – ташкентский, тунгус – тунгусский, черкес – черкесский.

Суффикс относительных прилагательных ***К*** пишется **после** ***Ц***, а **также при чередовании *К* на *Ц***: немец – немецкий – основа на Ц, суффикс К; калмык – калмыцкий, казак – казацкий.

Но почему сделано исключение для слов ***таджикский*** и ***узбекский*** с основой на ***К***?

Comment: Не совсем внятное обяснение из ПАСа. Если конечные согласные основы к и ч не чередуются с ц, то в прилагательных пишется −ск  (после к), напр.: узбекский (узбек), таджикский (таджик), моздокский (Моздок), −ск  или −еск  (после ч, см. § 90).

Comment: Они не чередуются по каким-то причинам или не могут чередоваться?  Здесь смысл или фонетика?

Comment: Трудно ответить. Хотя если отвечать на ваш вопрос, то,наверное, следует отметить, что то в одном случае суффикс к, в другом суффикс ск.

Comment: http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_109

Comment: Все это есть у Розенталя.  Но К – это не суффикс качества, а вариант ОТНОСИТЕЛЬНОГО суффикса СК для основ на Ц, в том числе с чередованием К/Ц. Но почему в одном случае есть чередование, а в другом нет?

Comment: таджик, узбек (-и-,-е-). казак, калмык (-а-,-ы-).

Comment: @user190920, и что?

Comment: @user190920  Фонетика?  Смягчение Ц после -и-. -е-?

Comment: Нужно больше примеров, тогда может быть можно будет утверждать что-то о фонетике. Исключения редко появляются просто так. Сказать, что что-то исключение - просто уйти от вопроса. Бывает, что называется "так повелось", в одной области так в другой сяк. Это да

Comment: Напишем так:  таджицкий, узбецкий. Ж, Ц смягчается, получается нерусское произношение)

Answer (score 1):

В качестве гипотезы. И калмык и казак начинаются на -к-. Поэтому, когда мы говорим, калмыкский и казакский в словах слишком много букв -к-, поперхнуться можно. Говорить и слышать эти глухие слова становится сложнее. Произносить и слышать звонкие калмыцкий и казацкий намного легче. Я, например, некоторые глухие русские слова специально изменяю на звонкие, чтобы лучше коммуницировать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за интерес к теме. Я позже добавлю кое-что по фонетике. Свои мысли-гипотезы о звуке Ц и его соседях.

Comment: Кабацкий, дурацкий еще. Может все таки дело в -а- и -ы- перед суффиксом, надо еще примерную базу наращивать.